# Couldn't change ArcGIS Web App Builder application spatial reference (wkid 102100)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I couldn't change ArcGIS Web App Builder application spatial reference (wkid 102100) to wkid 4326 even though I changed it in the configuration.
Is there anywhere else where I have to make changes to a config file? 
The one below is in WebAppBuilderForArcGIS2.6\server\apps\2\config.json

```
  "mapOptions": {
    "extent": {
      "xmin": -73.3563082698,
      "ymin": -33.485687785,
      "xmax": 61.373452187,
      "ymax": 29.4752271893,
      "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 4326
      }
    }
  },
```

What I am using:

- Web App Builder 2.6
  Javascript API 3.22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you modified is the map extent, which is defined by the xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax and the spatial reference. You can give a different coordinates, with a different spatial reference, but it won't change the Web Map spatial reference, it refers only to the coordinates you provide to the map extent.

A WebApp Builder app has an itemId, that you can find in the config file, for example: `"itemId": "b05788b519834f128aaf2dee0acd4a6b"`
Such property is the WebMap of the App. If you want to use another Spatial Reference, you have to set up a different WebMap, with a different Spatial reference. But the important thing here is that **the WebMap will have the spatial reference of the Basemap, because the Basemap establishes the coordinate system of the map** (see [ESRI doc](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/use/choose-basemap.htm)).

So you have to set up a WebMap with a Basemap that has as spatial reference the wkid 4326.